# How to log all the events performed on directory?

Tags: linux, directory, logs

How can I log all the events performed on a particular directory?

I want to log the entry of each directory modified within some time duration. I am using `find . -type d -mmin -5` command.

In addition to this, I want to put more details, when any directory is moved to another place, I need to add the below log details, eg.,

> directory "xyz" moved from "home/usr/xyz" => to "home/usr/documents/xyz"

Answer (score 10):

If using `Linux`, you should try `inotifywait` command, it's designed to listen events on files or directories.

```
inotifywait -m -r /dir
```

You can use a `while` loop over that to filter the output.

Moreover, it's very light : no need to `poll()` every N seconds, that's all the magic.

See http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `inotify` is Linux specific but the question is not tagged Linux. Good solutions are going to be OS specific like this one though.